# Gradle imports private maven dependency but looks for the wrong pom file name : double .pom.pom extension

Tags: maven, kotlin, gradle, pom.xml, github-package-registry

I'm trying to resolve my dependencies with Gradle. It worked fine until today.
My own dependency can't be found anymore. The dependency should be found using github package.
This is my conf :

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
    def propertiesFile = project.rootProject.file('local.properties')
    def props = new Properties()
    if (propertiesFile.exists()) {
        props.load(propertiesFile.newDataInputStream())
    }
    
    def githubPackagePassword = props.getProperty('github.package.password')
    def systemGithubPackagePassword = System.getenv('GIT_PACKAGE_PASSWORD')
    ext.github_package_password = githubPackagePassword != null ? githubPackagePassword : systemGithubPackagePassword
    
    buildscript {
        ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.20'
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
            mavenCentral()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3'
            classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
            classpath 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-alpha11'
            classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.6.1"
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
            classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appdistribution-gradle:1.3.1'
            classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.3.0'
    
            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }
    
    
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
            maven {
                url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
            }
            maven {
                url = uri("https://maven.pkg.github.com/SearchStartShare/3S-API")
                credentials {
                    username = "hidden username for stackoverflow"
                    password = github_package_password
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    task clean(type: Delete) {
        

    delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

I got the following error :

```
    Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
    > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
       > Could not find com.sss:sss-util:2.1.6-SNAPSHOT.
         Searched in the following locations:
           - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/sss/sss-util/2.1.6-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
           - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/sss/sss-util/2.1.6-SNAPSHOT/sss-util-2.1.6-SNAPSHOT.pom
           - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/sss/sss-util/2.1.6-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
           - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/sss/sss-util/2.1.6-SNAPSHOT/sss-util-2.1.6-SNAPSHOT.pom
           - https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/sss/sss-util/2.1.6-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
           - https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/sss/sss-util/2.1.6-SNAPSHOT/sss-util-2.1.6-SNAPSHOT.pom
           - https://maven.pkg.github.com/SearchStartShare/3S-API/com/sss/sss-util/2.1.6-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
           - https://maven.pkg.github.com/SearchStartShare/3S-API/com/sss/sss-util/2.1.6-SNAPSHOT/sss-util-2.1.6-20210411.090340-1.pom.pom
         Required by:
             project :app
    
    Possible solution:
     - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

The maven-metadata.xml has been well found
`https://maven.pkg.github.com/SearchStartShare/3S-API/com/sss/sss-util/2.1.6-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml`
But it doesn't find the pom file. But looks normal because there is a double `pom` extension !
`https://maven.pkg.github.com/SearchStartShare/3S-API/com/sss/sss-util/2.1.6-SNAPSHOT/sss-util-2.1.6-20210411.090340-1.pom.pom`

Why is there two pom extensions ?
What did I miss ?

PS : When I remove last `.pom` and I copy the url on google url search, Github ask me my credentials. After filling it, I got my pom file.

Just in case, this is content of the maven-metadata.xml

```
    com.ssssss-util2.1.6-SNAPSHOT20210411.0903401.pom20210411090347jar2.1.6-20210411.090340-120210411090342sha12.1.6-20210411.090340-1.jar20210411090343md52.1.6-20210411.090340-1.jar20210411090344pom2.1.6-20210411.090340-120210411090345sha12.1.6-20210411.090340-1.pom20210411090346md52.1.6-20210411.090340-1.pom20210411090347
    This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
    <metadata modelVersion="">
    <groupId>com.sss</groupId>
    <artifactId>sss-util</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <versioning>
    <snapshot>
    <timestamp>20210411.090340</timestamp>
    <buildNumber>1.pom</buildNumber>
    ...
    </snapshot>
    <lastUpdated>20210411090347</lastUpdated>
    <snapshotVersions>
    <snapshotVersion>
    <extension>jar</extension>
    <value>2.1.6-20210411.090340-1</value>
    <updated>20210411090342</updated>
    ...
    </snapshotVersion>
    <snapshotVersion>
    <extension>sha1</extension>
    <value>2.1.6-20210411.090340-1.jar</value>
    <updated>20210411090343</updated>
    ...
    </snapshotVersion>
    <snapshotVersion>
    <extension>md5</extension>
    <value>2.1.6-20210411.090340-1.jar</value>
    <updated>20210411090344</updated>
    ...
    </snapshotVersion>
    <snapshotVersion>
    <extension>pom</extension>
    <value>2.1.6-20210411.090340-1</value>
    <updated>20210411090345</updated>
    ...
    </snapshotVersion>
    <snapshotVersion>
    <extension>sha1</extension>
    <value>2.1.6-20210411.090340-1.pom</value>
    <updated>20210411090346</updated>
    ...
    </snapshotVersion>
    <snapshotVersion>
    <extension>md5</extension>
    <value>2.1.6-20210411.090340-1.pom</value>
    <updated>20210411090347</updated>
    ...
    </snapshotVersion>
    ...
    </snapshotVersions>
    ...
    </versioning>
    ...
    </metadata>
```

Android Gradle Plugin version : 4.1.3
Gradle version : 7.0
(I tried to change versions many times :( )

---

----------------    EDIT      --------------------

I declared my package as snapshot in the pom.xml

```
    <artifactId>sss-util</artifactId>
    <name>sss-util</name>
    <version>2.2.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

I just removed the suffix `-SNAPSHOT` now it works fine...
Not really a solution, I worked around the problem.
I thinks it's a bug from maven 3.5.4, don't really know